# distinguish connected keyboards on windows?

Tags: windows

I have a question regarding keyboard inputs.

I see many programmable keypads out there. I just wonder...is it possible to make a software as a replacement for programmable keypads? I am thinking following idea.

1. connect two keyboards to a computer.
2. make a software that distinguish each keyboard inputs to make one of keyboards as a programmable keypad.

I thought it would be possible, but all my friends say "no".

Comment: found similar question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587840/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-input-devices-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but pretty difficult - you'd have to have a device driver whose INF file specifically targets one of the keyboards (the driver chosen by PNP will always be the most specific match to the hardware), then write a HID driver that essentially replicates kbdhid.sys but instead of directly relaying the keys pressed, relays your programmed keys (or an easier solution would to have it always relay "weird" key combinations like Win+π, which you could then have a user-mode app watch for it via RegisterHotkey)

Check out [this page on WDF](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/wdf/default.mspx) to get started.