# How to distinguish between KeyBoard Numpad and external USB Numpad?

Tags: c++, input, keyboard

I try to write an little application for remapping my external Numpad for quite a while now, but I'm stuck. The way I am trying to do that is by figuring out when my external Numpad sends a keystroke via Raw Input API, then sending a VK with SendInput when a specific key on my external Numpad is pressed, and finally blocking the keystrokes the Numpad sends from being received by any application. But the last thing is where I am stuck.

When I try to Block input with BlockInput(TRUE), my application also doesn't receive any WM_INPUT Raw Input Messages, and I didn't came up with any other idea yet. I have read something about key hooks in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587840/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-input-devices-in-c), but there is no real solution mentioned. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput.aspx