# Separate input for additional 10-key keypad

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, directinput

I am writing Windows DirectX 11 software in C++ for which I would like to receive input from both a regular keyboard and a 10-key keypad. I would like a secondary user to be able to input from a 10-key keypad without disrupting the use of the full keyboard by the primary user. For example, if the primary user is typing into a text box, I would like the secondary user to be able to send 10-key data to the software to be handled separately so it does not affect the text box input.

I am currently using DirectInput for both mouse and keyboard. But if anyone knows of a solution through the Windows API, I would consider that as well.

When I create my keyboard device in DirectInput, I am currently using the GUID_SysKeyboard value, which lumps both keyboards into one so that my software can't discern the source of keyboard input. Is it possible to use EnumDevices to identify the two keyboards and create separate DirectInput devices? I imagine it would be, but I'm not sure how to go about identifying each device from the DIDEVICEINSTANCE structure provided to the EnumDevices callback. I would like to make this as generic as possible so it can be used with different combinations and models/brands of keyboards.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

(Note: I posted this same question on [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/635136-separate-input-for-additional-10-key-keypad/))

Comment: Anyone have thoughts on this? I'm hoping the lack of response is because I posted the question late on a Friday afternoon :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12533639/839436

Comment: Maybe look into [Raw input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536%28VS.85%29.aspx) [This is an example](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/) of a similar thing but using barcode scanners. Originally answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533367/differentiate-between-two-keyboards-in-a-keyboardhook?lq=1) @Tim, this is completelly off topic but is there any chance I could see how you implemented FW1FontWrapper [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708860/how-do-you-draw-text-in-directx-11/7879031#

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the numbers on the top row (under the F-Keys of course) are given the same value as the keypad numbers but for compatibility with all keyboards not just ones with keypads I would suggest just leaving it with the top row ones