# Can I get input keyboard Hardware ID in .net WPF KeyEventArgs?

Tags: wpf, keyeventargs

I have a .net wpf form examining keystrokes using:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

There are two 'keyboards': one is the standard input keyboard and the other is a USB credit card reader. **Do any of the KeyEventArgs properties allow me to tell which Hardware ID sent the text?**

Or is there a method I can call from PreviewKeyDown() to get the Hardware ID? I have looked through all the KeyEventArgs properties including the private ones I don't have access to and could find nothing specific to a Hardware ID.

Comment: Not saying that it is impossible, but, in the other hand if you are reading credit cards bear in mind that they follow standards which you can stick with, for example you can validate if the incoming stream for Track1 match regular expression:^%([A-Z])([0-9]{1,19})\^([^\^]{2,26})\^([0-9]{4}|\^)([0-9]{3}|\^)([^\?]+)\?$. If that is the case I can presume the input comes from card reader.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587840/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-input-devices-in-c-sharp

Comment: I am always able to identify card reader input: it starts with <DvcMsg,  ends with Return and is a 400-500 character string with an encrypted card number. That is not the issue and therefore I do not need to add sentinel characters as suggested in the article Gary referred me to. The issue is when a cashier accidently taps a key on the standard keyboard WHILE the card reader is sending. That key is embedded in the 'card reader' message. What I did learn from Gary's reference is that wm_input may be my only hope but I was trying to avoid that sort of low level coding.

Comment: I want to thank Gary for steering me towards wm_input. I found an absolutely excellent article with a library for handling keyboard devices using wm_input. So I did not have to write the low-level code after all. I stopped using PreviewKeyDown at all - such a pity Microsoft could not report the sending device in one of the KeyEventArgs properties. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distinguish between multiple input devices in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587840/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-input-devices-in-c-sharp)