# How to know which device caused the event to fire? C#

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have two keyboards connected to my PC and I subscribe to the keydown event of a control lets say a TextBox, is there any way in C# to identify which one of the keyboards caused the event?

Comment: Yes, put the camera on each keyboard. Just kidding. This question is not belong to SO.

Comment: @SeM How does it not belong here? It's totally on topic.

Comment: @Isuka do you see any code here? Or may be c# related question?

Comment: @SeM , you can see I have mentioned usercontrol and keydown event in my question, these terms are used in WPF I guess.

Comment: @Sameed anyway, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587840/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-input-devices-in-c-sharp/589326#589326) article may help you, maybe will solve your problem, maybe will give you an idea how to ask your question fully. Cheers.

Comment: @SeM , tthis answer complicates things and it is focused towards a Barcode scanner.

Comment: The link in the answer linked to by SeM is broken but it does give you an idea of where to start looking if you put in the effort. It suggests the use of the Raw Input API - if you try googling "Raw Input API two keyboards" you will find links like these https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard & https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective - they may give you some idea of how to achieve what you want. Without showing what efforts you have put in so far you are unlikely to get much help.